# ASP.NET Login & Register work in Visual Studio, but not when published to IIS

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis

I have recently set up authorization in my Web.Config file for my ASP.NET project.  For example:

```
  <location path="Shipping.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="Shipper, Admin"/>

    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>

</system.web>
```

This authorization works great when I run the ASP.NET page in development mode.  I can create users and restrict and allow them to certain pages.  When I publish this project to IIS, I get:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you are using Integrated security for connecting to database (check connectionstring). So I suggest you create a sql user, map it your database and then use this username and password for connection.

Comment: Mohsin Mehmood, can you explain exactly how to create an sql user/map it/ and use the username and password? Sorry to be such a noob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I was not closing the connection in the class before returning the value. I was closing it after, which created a ton of open connections causing the system to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that you have a problem between your web application and the database. I don't think it is related to the authentication, but to the connection string, you are using. If you can share the local connection string in your web.config, then I may help.

Comment: Here it is: add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Traceability\App_Data\aspnet-Traceability-3c37005d-e7c9-4ac9-b612-38d4ac4e6769.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Traceability-3c37005d-e7c9-4ac9-b612-38d4ac4e6769;Integrated Security=True"/>

Comment: First, check that the connection details are working by connecting directly from the SQL server management studio, or from visual studio to the database. I don't think it is a good idea to use "AttachDbFilename", instead specify the correct database name in "Initial Catalog". The names you are using are not good, use short and clear names.

Comment: To make a quick test, go to the management studio or whatever tool you have, enter the server name ".\SQLEXPRESS" and try to connect. If doesn't work, then I guess that the "." alias is not defined. So you need to explicitly enter the name of the server, in this case, it could be your machine name. Or you need to check google how to add an alias to SQL server.

Comment: I was able to connect to .\SQLEXPRESS through the SSMS.  Can you give me an example of what the connection string should look like?

Comment: Something like this : connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True"/. There are many possibilities, depend on how you are trying to connect. Try to remove "Integrated Security=True" and add username and password. Sometimes the firewall could cause such error because the application can't connect to the db. Try to disable it.